# Calling MPI from R to run C code

Tags: c, r, mpi, hpc

I have an R function which is essentially acting as a wrapper to a set of C functions - the R code calls the C code through `.C("...").`  This C code could be parallelized and compiled using some MPI implementation. However, having never used MPI before, I have no idea if such MPI-ed code would even be callable from R in a way that would let MPI work?

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing? I'm guessing the R MPI libraries are pointless for my purpose, given all the work is done deep within the C code. This would ultimate be run on HPC cluster, if that makes any difference?

Can you use mpicc to create a shared objected, and if such a shared object was called from R would a parallel implementation run, or would you just get the serial version (or indeed, as I suspect, would it just crash)?

I may well be missing info needed to understand the problem, so will update accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem confused.

You could just use the *existing* [Rmpi](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rmpi) package to spawn parallel execution of several R instances (on your different nodes) and each of those can use your `.C()`-called code as well.

Maybe you want to work through some simple examples to get a better feel about what can or cannot be done?

Comment: Maybe I am (in fairness, this is often the case). I wanted to avoid Rmpi because I don't think it's installed on the clusters. In my mind I wanted R to be executed serially, and the spawn off the C code which would use MPI.

However, this seems like a much better approach anyway (and I may be totally missing the point with my original train of thought).

Comment: The _everything needed has to be installed on each node_ part is the single biggest hurdle, I find. In practice, it helps to have all nodes share R packages via a common `/usr/local/` directory mounted from NFS. Other than that, you "just" have to deal with permissions (`ssh` helps) and general MPI config (hostnames). Not that big a deal, all things told.