# Running MPI C++ program from R using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, mpi

I know that I can run a MPI C++ program using x processors with `mpirun`:

```
mpirun -np x program-name
```

Is it possible to modify a MPI C++ program using Rcpp library such that it can be called from R using x processors without resorting to Rmpi library as suggested on [Calling MPI from R to run C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691779/calling-mpi-from-r-to-run-c-code) now?

For illustrative purpose, I have modified the MPI hello world program to be called from R:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int hello_world() {
  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  
  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
  
  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  
  // Print off a hello world message
  Rcout << "Hello world from processor rank " << world_rank << " out of " << world_size <<  " processors\n";
  
  // Finalize the MPI environment
  MPI_Finalize();
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I call the `hello_world` function from R, I get:

```
> library(Rmpihelloworld)
> hello_world()
Hello world from processor rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

Is it possible to call the `hello_world` function from R with x processors?

Comment: How about `system("mpirun -np x program-name")`?  That will run `mpirun` from C++, and will solve your program so long as you replace `Rout` with `std::cout` in your MPI code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and "sure". Call you `Rmpihelloworld::hello_world()` function from _script_ you launch with `Rscipt` (or `r`) which you launch from `mpirun`.  Now you can spray it easily over N nodes via MPI as folks have been doing that for many years. Also look at `slurm` and its R interface, and packages likes [`doMPI`[(https://cran.r-project.org/package=doMPI).  The question effectively has nothing to do with Rcpp besides helping you to write a C++ routine.

Comment: This has objectively nothing to do with Rcpp (other than Rcpp helping you to glue C++ code to R) so I am removing the tag. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't mind at all. I agree that my question is more about the use of mpi with C++ and R code after I read your comments. Thank you for helping to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by John Zwinck and Dirk Eddelbuettel, we ultimately need to use `mpirun` to run a MPI C++ program from R using x processors too.

To start, we can first wrap the R script containing the MPI C++ function callable from R into a file. For my illustrative example, we can wrap the following code into a file named `hello_world.R`:

```
library(Rmpihelloworld)
hello_world()
```

Then, we can use `mpirun -np x Rscript r-script-name` to call the MPI C++ program from R using x processors. For my example, we can run:

```
mpirun -np 8 Rscript hello_world.R
```

to call the MPI hello world C++ program from R using 8 processors:

```
Hello world from processor rank 4 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 5 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 6 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 3 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 0 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 1 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 2 out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor rank 7 out of 8 processors
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Comment: If you look at my web page listing [talks and presentation](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html) you will find a number of slide decks about introductions to high-performance computing with R mostly from the years 2008 to 2010. Several contain worked examples of what you did here, and extensions/variations around MPI with and without Slurm, often via `rmpi` but as I recall also with some direct C/C++ examples.  So there is really nothing new here.